# One-hot Encoding function output in Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr, one-hot-encoding

I'm curious as to the output of the `ft_one_hot_encoder` function in `sparklyr` in R. I tried to implement it to find an output that I couldn't use, before using the `ml_create_dummy_variables` instead.

I have some simple test data and a working spark connection:

```
require(dplyr)
require(sparklyr)
spark_connection<-spark_connect(master = 'yarn-client'
oneHotTest<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,1,3), b=rnorm(4))

> oneHotTest
   a         b
1 1 2.2221345
2 2 0.2010831
3 1 0.5932860
4 3 0.7223811
```

I can then copy the data over  and apply the `ft_one_hot_encoder`, and `ml_create_dummy_variables` functions:

```
oneHotTable<-copy_to(spark_connection, oneHotTest)
oneHotEncode<-ft_one_hot_encoder(oneHotTable, input.col = 'a', output.col = 'output')
oneHotDummy<-ml_create_dummy_variables(oneHotTable, 'a')
```

The results are given below, the `ml_create dummy variables` gives me my desired output:

```
> oneHotDummy
 Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_211f7b4485f4> [?? x 5]
 Database: spark_connection
      a          b   a_1   a_2   a_3
  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 -0.1524646     1     0     0
2     2 -0.5914959     0     1     0
3     1 -0.9588067     1     0     0
4     3 -1.5186872     0     0     1
```

Where as `ft_one_hot_encoder` gives me an output column that is `NULL` and I can't work with:

```
> oneHotEncode
 Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_211f3897a9c1> [?? x 3]
 Database: spark_connection
      a          b    output
  <dbl>      <dbl>    <list>
1     1 -0.7109400 <dbl [3]>
2     2 -0.9688218 <dbl [3]>
3     1  1.1678944 <dbl [3]>
4     3  0.6903080 <dbl [3]>

> oneHotEncode$output 
 NULL
```

Is there an issue with the way I'm implementing this function or am I just accessing the information wrong? I have also tried reading the data back in from spark to no avail.

Comment: What it gives when you change `ft_one_hot_encoder()` with `output.col = NULL`?

Comment: `Error in ensure_scalar_character(output.col) : 
  'NULL' is not a length-one character vector`

Answer (score 1):

In sparklyr 0.6.0 you can use this

```
x <- sdf_separate_column(oneHotDummy, column = 'output', into='new')
```