# How to hot encode/generate dummy columns using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, one-hot-encoding, sparklyr, dummy-variable

I know there are number of questions similar to this here but 1) most of the solutions rely on deprecated functions like `ml_create_dummy_variables` and 2) other solutions are incomplete.

Is there a function or an approach to easily hot encode a categorical variable into multiple dummy variables in sparklyr?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543994/how-to-correctly-use-ft-string-indexer-and-ft-one-hot-encoder-for-multiple-colum) asks for a solution in SparkR, incidentally a sparklyr solution is given that only works when the categories are unique in a given column, which renders its pointless.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543994/how-to-correctly-use-ft-string-indexer-and-ft-one-hot-encoder-for-multiple-colum), results in a single dummy instead of a dummy for each category (grabs the first category). This is also the solution I stumbled onto (based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928335/one-hot-encoding-function-output-in-sparklyr)), which does not cut it:

```
iris_sdf <- copy_to(sc, iris, overwrite = TRUE)

iris_sdf %>%
  ft_string_indexer(input_col = "Species", output_col = "species_num") %>%
  mutate(cat_num = species_num + 1) %>%
  ft_one_hot_encoder("species_num", "species_dum") %>%
  ft_vector_assembler(c("species_dum"))
```

I'm looking for a solution that will take `Species` from the `iris` dataset and generate three columns -one for each category in `Species` (virginica, setosa, and versicolor). Using R, `fastDummies` package has what I need, but I'm left wondering how to achieve similar functionality in sparklyr.

Again, I'll note that `ml_create_dummy_variables` (suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039558/creating-dummy-variables-in-sparklyr)) produced the following error:

```
Error in ml_create_dummy_variables(., "species_num", "species_dum") : Error in ml_create_dummy_variables(., "species_num", "species_dum") : 
  could not find function "ml_create_dummy_variables"
```

Note: I'm using `sparklyr_1.3.1`